# Increase loop device in debian squeeze

Tags: debian

I'm using Debian (squeeze), I want to increase the loop devices, 
I have checked in my system there is no file "/etc/modules.conf" and "/etc/conf.modules" . 
I searched in Google I didn't get the details for squeeze

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Squeeze, the module list should be in /etc/modules. Specify in that file e.g.:

```
loop max_loop=64
```